# Can I reposition AdSense ads with Javascript (for responsive purposes)?

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

I have a responsive blog where ads are displayed in the sidebar. On mobile devices however, the sidebar is pushed to the bottom below the posts.

So what I'd like to do is move the ads from the sidebar and insert them into the post itself on mobile devices
[image]

I do this using javascript:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="article">
        <div class="post">
            <p class="intro"></p>
            <p class="text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="adbox-1"></div>
    </div>    
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // AD REPOSITION
        if ($(window).width() < 769) {
            $('.ad-box1').insertAfter($('.intro'));           
        }
     });
</script>
```

The ads are always loaded in the sidebar, but if the screen width is below 768px, they will be moved somewhere else.

I wonder if this would violate AdSense terms of service?

Comment: In my understanding that is not allowed, and this may be what you actually want http://jsfiddle.net/galeksic/r18v4v8m/

Comment: Do you have any source on why it wouldn't be allowed? Thanks for the code btw, but I'm afraid I can't use it. I have to move the ad dynamically via javascript, if I use media query + display: none, I'd have to add the ad code manually for every post.

Comment: That is why I said it is my understanding, because I can't provide source, but (for me) it is obvious: if you would be allowed to move parsed AdSense advertisement, what could stop you to reuse it once again, or few, or several times, maybe even on another pages? That parsed ad have many parameters attached, like timestamp, coordinates on the page, etc. so I believe moving would make it invalid. Btw. I don't see any reason why would you "need to add code manually for every post" if you use media queries, and if you do need, then there might be something wrong with your site design / concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [@media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) are simpler.

You load the two ad units and under 768px you hide one and show the other. [This is valid](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en).

The solution you are using is good but as you insert the new ad unit under 768, you also need to remove the other.

[This guide](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en) from Google explains what you can't do:

> 1. Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g., display:none), unless you're implementing a responsive ad unit.
> 2. Implementing AdSense ad code in a way that covers content
> 3. Using any means to force the display of more than three AdSense ad units on a page
> 4. Manipulating the ad targeting using hidden keywords, IFRAMEs, or any other method
> 5. Distributing ads in emails or software
> 6. Floating ads or units that slide to attract unwarranted attention

Media queries are possible.

Anyway both of the approaches seems valid by Adsense.

Comment: The only way for me to load an ad inside the posts is to edit all my post 1 by 1 and mnually add an ad code for each one. If both approaches are valid, moving the ad dynamically would be easier.

Comment: I supposed you were using a CMS, if so you don't need to edit the posts 1 by 1.

Comment: I'm using Tumblr which limits my ability to manipulate posts as I don't have access to server-side script. That's why I have to move it dynamically through javascript. I'm still uncertain about this method as @galeksic thinks it does violate Google's TOS.

Comment: a) not being able to edit posts one by one is not a valid reason b) even the officially approved AdSense code (with media queries) won't _move_ already rendered (existing) advertisement from sidebar into the post: it will _request another_ ad from the post, for the post. That is completely different and for me it is obvious that .insertAfter() is not an option. c) If you want, we can continue on https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/v6LkFTCLBZM/3M1QAb15B7MJ and if you get the official answer, I think it would be nice if you could update your question here with that answer.

Comment: For what I read, it is a valid approach because we're not changing the original code of the ad and we're not floating or sliding the ads to attract attention. The fact is that, if the user is accessing from a device with under 768px, nothing will be moved but directly loaded with the appropriate requests from the ad. The only way the ad will move is if you load on a desktop and resize the screen, otherwise the request will be original, and even in this situation seems valid.

Comment: if hiding the ad unit using css - make sure it is responsive ad unit. if not dont add in this way..   instead using javascript is better to load ad unit - based on screen size